# How to make this work with Guzzle

Tags: php, guzzle

I am trying to use Guzzle instead of curl to make an API request.  This API requires the post fields value be prepended with request= for some reason.  How can I do this with Guzzle?

Here is how it would be done with curl:

```
$postfields = json_encode(array('field1' => 'some value'));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://someapi.com/PostRequest');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "request=$postfields");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$curlerror = curl_errno($ch);
if (!empty($curlerror))
{
    echo 'curl error: ' . $curlerror;
}
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

I have tried this but the API responds back with an invalid format error.

```
$postfields = json_encode($request);

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://someapi.com/PostRequest', array('request' => $postfields));
```

Same error with this.

```
    $postfields = json_encode($request);

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://someapi.com/PostRequest', array("request=$postfields"));
    print_r($response);
```

If I try this Guzzle gives error that parameter 3 is not an array.

```
$postfields = json_encode($request);

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://someapi.com/PostRequest', "request=$postfields");
print_r($response);
```

This may be a case of poor API design and I am not able to use Guzzle.

Comment: try not json encoding `$postfields`?

Comment: the api is expecting it to be json encoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I'm surprised your Curl example works, as you're supposed to `urlencode` the data.

However, the problem is that the third parameter is not the data to be posted. It's an options array, of which the POST data is one option, which you need to send with the key `form_params`:

```
$client->request('POST', 'https://someapi.com/PostRequest', array('query'=>array('request' => $postfields)));
// or
$client->request('POST', 'https://someapi.com/PostRequest', ['form_parms'=>['request'=>$postfields]]);
```

This is [specified in the documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I do understand now about the different options.  query would not work here as it just adds the json string to the URL as query parameters.  I tried the various other options too but none would work.  I am pretty sure that this is a case of poor API design and I will not be able to use guzzle.

Comment: @TomVaughan You're right: it should have been `form_params` rather than `query`. The answer is updated. It's not a problem with the API or the client.